# What is the difference in AWS for authenticating a mobile user with STS or Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sts

I am wondering if STS is essentially like Cognito in terms of authenticating a federated user?

Per AWS document:[AWS Security Token Service (STS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)

> AWS Security Token Service (STS) is a web service that enables you to request temporary, limited-privilege credentials for AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) users or for users that you authenticate (**federated users**).

Per AWS document: [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)

> Amazon Cognito lets you add user sign-up, sign-in, and access control to your web and mobile apps quickly and easily. Amazon Cognito scales to millions of users and supports sign-in with social identity providers, such as Facebook, Google, and Amazon, and enterprise identity providers via SAML 2.0.

**What is the difference and use case for STS and Cognito in terms of authenticating a mobile user for a mobile app**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, understand that Cognito encompasses two related services, [User Pools and Identity Pools](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pools-identity-pools/).

In short, a user pool is a user database with all the frills: auth, MFA, groups, password resets, etc. It allows a user to provide a username and password, and if they're valid it gives them a token to prove they are an authentic user. It provides *authentication*.

An id pool *maps* from users to AWS credentials. In order to map to AWS credentials, it needs some concept of a user, and this has to be provided by *somebody*. This can be a user pool, or a 3rd party. Regardless, you can only use an id pool once you have a user token of some sort, and then you can use that to ask the id pool: "give me the credentials (if any) this user may use". The id pool provides the credentials you need for *authorization* against AWS services.

---

> What is the difference and use case for STS and Cognito in terms of authenticating a mobile user for a mobile app?

Consider the path `user login -A-> user auth token -B-> aws credentials`.

1. STS *only* provides temporary credentials. STS has no concept of a user, it only knows whether the caller has the permissions to access credentials, and which credentials those are. *"For users that you authenticate"* means **only you** handle all of authentication, then call STS for credentials to give those users. It fulfills neither arrow `A` nor arrow `B`.
2. Cognito user pools fulfill arrow `A` above.
3. Cognito id pools fulfill arrow `B` above.

If you want to do both arrow `A` and arrow `B` yourself, you can use STS as part of your solution.

If you want to do just arrow `A` yourself, you can use id pools to handle arrow `B` (id pools actually use STS on the back end). You would tell id pools the identity provider that will be handling arrow `A` (e.g. Facebook), then *you* would handle the logic of getting Facebook to authenticate your users for you. You would take the Facebook auth token a user gets, and pass it to id pools to get credentials back.

If you want to do the least amount of work, you would use user pools to handle arrow `A` and id pools to handle arrow `B`. You can still use a third-party auth provider (e.g. Facebook), underneath user pools, but you would point id pools at user pools, and user pools at the third party. Then, user pools handles all the logic of part `A` for you (you write zero Facebook auth API code).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation